Designing a schema for data aggregation
First of all, I'm mainly looking for ideas and approaches that I can look into when it comes to this design, as opposed to complete solutions.
I have an application that needs to show an aggregate of multiple data sources. Sources have some fields in common, but they may also have some extra data attached to it based on the source. There are some important non functional requirements to consider when designing this DB:

Performance is critical, since this DB runs on mobile devices.
The aggregated data needs to be available as soon as possible.

Below is a simplified sample data set. The idea is that the user should see the best name match that we have.
  Source           name                email                  imageUrl 

Twitter,       Twitter Mike,            null,           images.com/twittermike
AppBackend,   AppBackend Mike,          null,                   null
Facebook,      Facebook Mike,     mike@facebook.com,    images.com/facebookmike

Priority: AppBackend > Twitter > Facebook

Output: AppBackendMike, mike@facebook.com, images.com/twittermike

How I was thinking to design this is as follows:

A table for raw users
A table for aggregated users
A separate table for extra data that is source specific

RawUser(id: PK, aggUserId: FK, name, source, email, imageUrl)

AggregatedUser(id: PK, name, source, email, imageUrl)

Data(id: PK, rawUserId: PK, extra fields)

The downsides of this approach are:

I have to perform the aggregation manually whenever there's a change in users - probably through triggers. I don't think there's a way around this though.
Tables are not normalized. There will be plenty of null values.
Mixing multiple data sources in the same table might be a bad idea long term. It's easy to add source specific columns.


no no aggregated table, but you can use a Source table where you put AppBackend as first row, so that the source is selected always first

Not exactly clear what you're looking to achieve. Can you perhaps add an example query or two and the expected results you'd want to see from them?

@nbk Can you give more details as how that would work? I'm not sure I quite understand. How do I connect this Source table with the rest?

@J.D. I'm not sure if I can add a qurey, but I gave an example in the post with the expected output. I can improve on that if it's not clear enough.
As for my proposal, it would work as follows

Insert a new raw user into RawUser
Query all users that have a similar name e.g. to keep it simple, any names containing Mike should be aggregated together
Choose the best data e.g. first non-null field based on priority, or some other conditions such as timestamp
Insert the aggregated user into AggregateUser


@aarnaut "I'm not sure if I can add a qurey" - Why's that? Unfortunately your provided example output doesn't convey why you chose the values you did from the source dataset.

Right, I didn't add this info, thank you. It should take the first non-null value based on the priority. So, in this case, email is from FB, because there isn't one available in AppBackend or Twitter source.

Sounds like it's just one or two left joins (or possibly a lateral APPLY and TOP 1) along with an ISNULL or COALESCE, but may be misunderstanding something. If so, why can't you just do that and ensure your tables are indexed correctly?
